# Trying to pass directory as an argument

Tags: r, function, directory, arguments, lapply

I have a few files in a directory that I want to merge. I am using lapply for the same. It is a repetitive task, and I wanted to write a function for the same and pass the directory as an argument. However I am done so and nothing seems to happen. If I run the same without passing it as a function, the method works.

Code without the function:

```
directory="S:/monthly/Jan"
list<-list.files(path=directory,full.names=T)
list
data<-lapply(list, read.table, sep="|", header=T)
```

With function:

```
function_data_combined<-function(directory)
{
list<-list.files(path=directory,full.names=T)
list
data<-lapply(list, read.table, sep="|", header=T)
}
function_data_combined("S:/monthly/Jan")
```

The function does not throw any error, it just does not creates the list.

Comment: You're missing the return command. At the end of it all, Y dont you do `return(data)`. Do it just before you close the function loop (})

Answer (score 2):

Add `return(data)` to your code (At the end, before closing the function (})

```
function_data_combined <- function(directory)
{
  mylist <- list.files(path = directory, full.names = TRUE)
  lapply(mylist, read.table, sep = "|", header = TRUE)
  # Or we can be explicit
  # res <- lapply(mylist, read.table, sep = "|", header = TRUE)
  # return(res)
}

#run function
myData <- function_data_combined("S:/monthly/Jan")
```